# Spark fails to merge parquet files (INTEGER -> DECIMAL)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I've got 2 parquets files.

The first one contains the following column: **DECIMAL: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)**

The second one has the same column, but with a different type: **DECIMAL: integer (nullable = true)**

I want to merge them, but I can't simply read them separatedly and throw a cast into the specific column, because this is part of an app that receives lots of distinct parquet schemas. I need something that would cover every scenario.

I am reading both like this:

```
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(['path_to_file_one', 'path_to_file_2'])
```

It fails with the error below when I try to display the data

> Parquet column cannot be converted. Column: [DECIMAL], Expected:
> DecimalType(38,18), Found: INT32

I am using Azure Databricks with the following configs:

- DBR: 7.1
- Spark 3.0.0

I have uploaded the parquet files here: https://easyupload.io/m/su37e8

Is there anyway I can force spark to autocast null columns into the type of the same column in the other dataframe?

It should be easy, all the columns are nullable...

Comment: You could try to provide own schema or use correct schema from 1st file to read 2nd file.

Comment: This wouldn't solve my problem because this is part of an app that receives lots of distinct parquet schemas. I need something that would cover every scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected if you are providing external schema with column datatype definition as a decimal and that column contains decimal(38,18).

[image]

We found that it's a limitation with the spark. Columns with datatype decimal(38,18).

Try `df.show()` to display the results.

[image]

Comment: I saw in the docs that spark supports decimal(38,38), is there any open request saying what limitation it is exactly?

Comment: Also, I will do some processing and saving, and these are also failing. I thought I was able to do counts, but actually it is failing too.

Comment: One more thing: I just figured that the show() only works if I don't show the row with INT schema: 

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, asc
df.where(col("id") > "9995").show() --> Same error here